# SQL Server stored procedure to insert in multiple tables a

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, `custlogin` and `custinfo`:

custlogin:

```
custid int primary key auto notnull
custusename varchar(25)
custpassword varchar(50)
```

custinfo:

```
custid foriegnkey custlogin.custid ondelete set NULL
custfirstname varchar(25)
custlastname  varchar(25)
custaddress   varchar(100)
```

I want to write a stored procedure which will insert into both tables

More precisely, insert into custlogin with custusername custpassword, which would return custid for use as foreign key for custinfo.

I have searched much but I didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like below. You can use **SCOPE_IDENTITY()** to get the last autogenerated ID withing the scope which is this stored proc in this case:

```
create procedure NameOfYourProcedureHere
as
begin

    insert into custlogin(custusename, custpassword) 
        values ('','') -- put values here (from parameters?)

    insert into custinfo(custid, custfirstname, custlastname, custaddress)
        values (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), '', '', '')  -- put other values here (from parameters?)

end
```

Comment: you answered on your own question after 1 minute since it was asked? hmm... smells like something wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you insert 1 row to `custlogin`, you could use [@@IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql) or [Scope_identity()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql) to get new inserted id.

If you insert multiple rows, then use [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) to get multiple new inserted ids.

You could see an example here: http://rextester.com/TWXO81648

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Thanks @marc_s, .....